# area under parametric curve

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, parametric

I have difficulty on how to eliminate parameter especially the equation involved trigonometry equation.

The question is asking for the area bounded by the curve , the 2 axes and the line $y=1$.

$x=4 \sin t$

$y=\cot t$

where $t$ is in the range $(0, \pi)$.
I have tried to use the trigonometric formula 
$1+ \cot^2 t =\csc^2 t$

but I got the wrong answer.The answer given is 4ln[(square root 2)+1].

Comment: can you draw the curve?

Comment: The curve is not given by the question.

Comment: yes it is, it is parametrically given, can you draw it or not?

Comment: no, I don't know how to draw

Comment: put t=0 and find x and y, put t = 0.1 and find x and y, do a few steps or use wolfram alpha to draw it for you, it is fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Desmos plot of the relevant part of the curve looks like this:

[image]

The desired area is simply the area "under" (to the left of) the curve from $y=0$ to $y=1$.

We now express $x$ in terms of $y$. Since $1+\cot^2t=\csc^2t=\frac1{\sin^2t}$ and thus $\frac1{1+\cot^2t}=\sin^2t$, we have
$$x=4\sin t=\frac4{\sqrt{1+\cot^2t}}=\frac4{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$$
So the desired area is
$$\int_0^1\frac4{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\,dy=4[\sinh^{-1}y]_0^1=4\sinh^{-1}1=4\ln(1+\sqrt2)$$
The last equality is well-known; see e.g. [OEIS A091648](https://oeis.org/A091648).